# connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000",

Tags: nginx

I got this error when I want to open my website:

```
2015/01/27 07:04:38 [error] 1727#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 62.217.151.69, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.alapar.az"
```

**How can I resolve it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that php-fpm or whatever you use as fastcgi backend is running and accepting connections at 127.0.0.1:9000